# Search and replace regex in large files without getting OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, regex

I created a little code which searches for a Regex string and replaces that with something else, it then creates a new output file with the changes made.
The code seems to work well with smaller files, but for 100 MB or larger files I am giving the System.OutOfMemoryException' error.

Here's my code:

```
string foldername = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
    String.Format("FIXED_{0}.tmx",
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox1.Text)));

string text = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<seg\b[^>]*>", "<seg>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<seg>
                    </tuv>", "<seg></seg></tuv>", RegexOptions.Multiline);

File.WriteAllText(foldername, text);
```

Visual studio highlights the `string text = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);`section.
I thought that maybe using File.ReadAllLines would work better, but I was not able to make it work with regex.

Can anybody help me on this? I am newbie to C# and probably my code is not the best one.

Comment: You'll want to read/replace/write line by line if you are receiving a memory exception.  Try looking at [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @Sam it sounds like even that's not robust enough; the matches likely *span lines.*

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud then it seems like OP's only option is to increase memory..since they will need to read the entire file into a string at once.

Comment: @Sam, that's probably not the right solution either, but I will not purport the solution is going to be simple.

Comment: In second replacement do you need exact number of whitespaces? Or it can be written as `<seg>\s*</tuv>`?

Comment: Is your input well-formed xml?

Comment: @mikez Given the fact that OP replaces `<seg> </tuv>`, then I guess that it's not so well-formed.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov yes I see that now.

Comment: Actually I wrote this to fix XML files which were not well-formed. The <seg> tag should not have any attribute inside it, and should always have its corresponding closing tag </seg>.

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov it can be written as `<seg>\s*</tuv>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to implement the replacement by yourself. The following is the sample code which uses state-machine to replace `<seg\b[^>*]>` with `<seg>`. The only problem it has, that if the file is ended with `<seg attr=""`, then only `<seg` will be written to the output.

```
enum TruncateSegState
{
    Idle,
    TagStart,
    TagStartS,
    TagStartSE,
    TagStartSEG,
    TagSEG
}

static void TruncateSeg(StreamReader input, StreamWriter output)
{
    TruncateSegState state = TruncateSegState.Idle;
    while (!input.EndOfStream)
    {
        char ch = (char)input.Read();
        switch (state)
        {
            case TruncateSegState.Idle:
                if (ch == '<')
                    state = TruncateSegState.TagStart;
                output.Write(ch);
                break;
            case TruncateSegState.TagStart:
                if (ch == 's')
                    state = TruncateSegState.TagStartS;
                else
                    state = TruncateSegState.Idle;
                output.Write(ch);
                break;
            case TruncateSegState.TagStartS:
                if (ch == 'e')
                    state = TruncateSegState.TagStartSE;
                else
                    state = TruncateSegState.Idle;
                output.Write(ch);
                break;
            case TruncateSegState.TagStartSE:
                if (ch == 'g')
                    state = TruncateSegState.TagStartSEG;
                else
                    state = TruncateSegState.Idle;
                output.Write(ch);
                break;
            case TruncateSegState.TagStartSEG:
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
                    state = TruncateSegState.TagSEG;
                else
                {
                    state = TruncateSegState.Idle;
                    output.Write(ch);
                }
                break;
            case TruncateSegState.TagSEG:
                if (ch == '>')
                {
                    state = TruncateSegState.Idle;
                    output.Write(ch);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("temp.txt"))
    TruncateSeg(reader, writer);
```

After you generated `temp.txt`, you use it as input for the next method, which adds missing `</seg>` tag.

```
enum ReplaceSegTuvState
{
    Idle,
    InsideSEG
}

static void ReplaceSegTuv(StreamReader input, StreamWriter output)
{
    ReplaceSegTuvState state = ReplaceSegTuvState.Idle;
    StringBuilder segBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    while (!input.EndOfStream)
    {
        char ch = (char)input.Read();
        switch (state)
        {
            case ReplaceSegTuvState.Idle:
                if (ch == '<')
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[4];
                    int bufferActualLength = input.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    output.Write('<');
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bufferActualLength);
                    if (bufferActualLength == buffer.Length && "seg>".SequenceEqual(buffer))
                    {
                        segBuffer.Clear();
                        state = ReplaceSegTuvState.InsideSEG;
                    }
                }
                else
                    output.Write(ch);
                break;
            case ReplaceSegTuvState.InsideSEG:
                if (ch == '<')
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[5];
                    int bufferActualLength = input.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bufferActualLength == buffer.Length && "/tuv>".SequenceEqual(buffer))
                    {
                        output.Write("</seg>");
                        output.Write("</tuv>");
                        state = ReplaceSegTuvState.Idle;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.Write(segBuffer.ToString());
                        output.Write('<');
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bufferActualLength);
                        state = ReplaceSegTuvState.Idle;
                    }
                }
                else if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
                {
                    output.Write(segBuffer.ToString());
                    output.Write(ch);
                    state = ReplaceSegTuvState.Idle;
                }
                else
                    segBuffer.Append(ch);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("temp.txt"))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
    ReplaceSegTuv(reader, writer);
```

Comment: Although this works almost great, there are cases where the `<seg></tuv>` appears instead of `<seg></seg></tuv>`. Even if this `<seg></seg>` tags has nothing in between they should appear. This could also be represented as `<seg/></tuv>`

Comment: @DanF It was given as idea how to go further. I added the implementation for the second step.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Memory Managed Files; MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

They seem to be a recommended way to handle very large files.

Comment: It won't help with regex, since it requires string.