# How to replace extended ASCII characters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to replace non-printable characters ie extended ASCII characters from a HUGE string.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(txtfileName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show( Regex.Replace(line,
              @"\p{Cc}",
              a => string.Format("[{0:X2}]", " ")
            )); ;

            }
```

this doesnt seem to be working.

EX:
AAÂAA should be converted to AA AA

Comment: What are you replacing them to? With what value? Also what is the Encoding format?

Comment: @Sadiq  AAÂAA should be converted to AA AA

Comment: You have to say which character set you mean by "extended ASCII" because there are several dozen. And, they don't cover the thousands of characters in Unicode. Or, do you actually want replace all characters except the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/) characters?

Comment: Basic latin only. I dont want new lines or tabs either. Space is fine.

Comment: Why do you give "Â" as an example of "non-printable?" How about replacing the control characters with the corresponding control pictures characters, as done in the chart of C0 Controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Encoding to be [UTF8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.text.encoding.utf8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) try this:

```
string strReplacedVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
        Encoding.Convert(
            Encoding.UTF8,
            Encoding.GetEncoding(
                Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName,
                new EncoderReplacementFallback(" "),
                new DecoderExceptionFallback()
                ),
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line)
        )
);
```

Comment: That works. I am going to mark it as answer. 
Btw can you by any chance also tell me how can i update the textfile .. line by line..? The text file is huge. I cant read it at once.

Comment: Don't you think it would be better for performance to write all text in memory rather than replacing text line by line in file with I/O intensive functions?

Comment: The file could be over 300MB. I am getting out of memory exception.

Comment: @Arbaaz What you have done (File.ReadLines()) already doing it (reading line by line instead of at once) - don't be deceived by the name `ReadLines` ;)

Comment: @Ian Yes Ian I am reading it line by line but my question is how can I also update/replace line by line? I am picking up a line replacing unwanted characters.. now i want to replace it with the new cleaned line.

Comment: @Arbaaz : You will have to do some sort of buffering and achieve this i believe. You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046121/search-and-replace-regex-in-large-files-without-getting-outofmemoryexception)

Comment: @Arbaaz if your data is large size (300MB) and you need it to be fast you may seriously need to consider the performance issue here, especially if you use `overkill` method like `Regex`. It could be that checking the character one by one + using `unsafe` is the fastest possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are opening the file as UTF-8, it must be. So, its code units are one byte and UTF-8 has the very nice feature of encoding characters above ␡ with bytes exclusively above 0x7f and characters at or below ␡ with bytes exclusively at or below 0x7f.

For efficiency, you can rewrite the file in place a few KB at a time.

*Note: that some characters might be replaced by more than one space, though.*

```
// Operates on a UTF-8 encoded text file
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    const int size = 4096;
    var buffer = new byte[size];
    int count; 
    while ((count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
    {
        var changed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // obliterate all bytes that are not encoded characters between ␠ and ␡ 
            if (buffer[i] < ' ' | buffer[i] > '\x7f')
            {
                buffer[i] = (byte)' ';
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        if (changed)
        {
            stream.Seek(-count, SeekOrigin.Current);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
}
```